# Is GridView in WPF support row Edit function

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I hope to add row edit funtion to gridview in WPF, the code snippet is as following:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="170">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Grade" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Grade}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I have seen some infos about DataGrid, but if there exist any method to make row edit funtion for gridview,
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to change `TextBlock` to `TextBox`.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Better way is to use `DataGrid` which has `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mail">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```